# Second menu level hides third one although z-index is lower

Tags: css, menu, hide, z-index

Regarding my navigation I have the problem that the second level is covered by the video or other elements that are created by javascript (visible when you hover "Hier lebe ich" or "Am Meer"):
http://www.ulrichbangert.de/orchid/mediaelement/2013-03-25_Pleione_Ueli_Wackernagel_Pearl.php
No problem, I thought, and gave the second level a higher z-index but lower than that one of the third level. But now the second level hides the third one partly although it's z-index is lower:
http://www.ulrichbangert.de/orchid/mediaelement/2013-03-25_Pleione_Ueli_Wackernagel_Pearl_zindex.php
(Hover the menu items below "Blumen und Pflanzen" and open the third level.)
CSS:

```
ul#Navigation li ul {
z-index: 998;

ul#Navigation li ul li {
z-index: 998;

ul#Navigation li ul li ul {
z-index: 999;
```

What is the reason for this and how can I fix it?
Best regards - Ulrich

Comment: did you see that i updated my answer?

Answer (score 0):

remove z-index from `ul#Navigation li ul li` and the problem goes away

Comment: Hallo Chris, thank you for your answer but in the meantime I had already found a solution in a german computer forum. Works fine now: http://www.ulrichbangert.de/orchid/mediaelement/2013-03-25_Pleione_Ueli_Wackernagel_Pearl.php

Comment: i answered this 2 days ago. can you mark it as correct please?